# VB.NET - SQL Data not written before 2nd operation

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb6, vb.net-2010

I have a routine that pulls in data from a text file and writes it to an SQL Database.

After writing the data I try and perform operations on the data, but some of the data is missing, I presume it's in a cached write and hasn't made it to the database yet.

If I close the programme and then run it to perform the 2nd operation it works fine, as I take it that the data has finally made its way to disk.

My question is in **VB6** I had a **BeginTrans** and **CommitTrans** statement that would buffer and then rite the data to disk.

**Is this what I need in the above case and how would I do it in VB.net?**

```
    FileOpen(1, cPath, OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read)
    cText = LineInput(1)
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        cText = ""
        cText = Trim(LineInput(1))
        If Not Trim(VB.Left(cText, 1)) = cDelimiter Then
            'decode line
            cFullName = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cTitle = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cSurname = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cInitials = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cForename = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cEUPN = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cEmail = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cClass = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cSubjectCode = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cSubject = VB.Left(Trim(cText), 21)
        Else
            'Now import Class Information
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cClass = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1)) : cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cSubjectCode = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1)) : cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cSubject = VB.Left(Trim(cText), 21)
        End If
        '

        ' Does the Member of Staff have any Classess Assigned to them?
        If Trim(cClass) <> "" Then
            'Check for Name else we are doing a second class
            If Trim(cFullName) <> "" Then
                If VerboseOutput Then Console.WriteLine(cForename & " " & cSurname & " " & cEUPN)
                'SAVE DATA TO DATABASE
                'Check if Student is in SQL database
                'Dim query As String = String.Empty
                query = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Staff WHERE EUPN = '" & cEUPN & "' AND AccYear = '" & AccademicYear & "'"
                Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
                    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                        With comm
                            .Connection = conn
                            .CommandText = query
                            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        End With
                        Try
                            conn.Open()
                            Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(comm.ExecuteScalar())
                            totalRow = count
                        Catch ex As SqlException
                            WriteToLogFile("Staff: ", ex.Message)
                            Console.Write("Staff - " & ex.Message.ToString())
                        End Try
                    End Using
                End Using
                'conn.Close()
                If totalRow = 0 Then
                    cFullName = cForename + " " + cSurname
                    If VerboseOutput Then Console.Write(cFullName & vbCrLf)
                    cQueryIS = "INSERT INTO Staff (AccYear, eupn, title, fullname, forename, surname, initials, WorkEmail)  "
                    cQueryIS &= "VALUES (@cAccYear, @cEupn, @cTitle, @cFullname, @cForename, @cSurname, @cInitials, @cWorkEmail)"
                    Using dbConnectionSQL As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
                        Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                            With comm
                                .Connection = dbConnectionSQL
                                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                .CommandText = cQueryIS
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAccYear", AccademicYear)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cEupn", cEUPN)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cTitle", cTitle)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cFullname", cFullName)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cforename", cForename)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cSurname", cSurname)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cInitials", cInitials)
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cWorkEmail", cEmail)
                            End With
                            Try
                                dbConnectionSQL.Open()
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            Catch ex As SqlException
                                WriteToLogFile("Staff Insert", ex.Message)
                                Console.Write("Staff Insert - " & ex.Message.ToString())
                                Console.Write(cFullName)
                            End Try
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End If
            End If
            'Now Add to Staff Classes Database
            cQueryIS = "INSERT INTO StaffClasses (accyear, eupn, class, subjectcode, subject)  "
            cQueryIS &= "VALUES (@cAccYear, @cEupn, @cclass, @csubjectcode, @csubject)"
            Using dbConnectionSQL As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
                Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                    With comm
                        .Connection = dbConnectionSQL
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        .CommandText = cQueryIS
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAccYear", AccademicYear)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cEupn", cEUPN)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cclass", cClass)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@csubjectcode", cSubjectCode)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@csubject", cSubject)
                    End With
                    Try
                        dbConnectionSQL.Open()
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Catch ex As SqlException
                        WriteToLogFile("Add Staff", ex.Message)
                        Console.Write("Staff Class Insert - " & ex.Message.ToString() + vbCrLf)
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    Loop
    FileClose(1)
```

If I try and perform a select after this it says part the data is not there.

Here is the second sub, which is called straight after the above:

```
   Dim cPath As String = ReadConfigurationFile("Class=")
    Dim FromStaffEUPN As String
    Dim ToStaffEUPN As String
    Dim FromClass As String
    Dim FromSubjectCode As String
    Dim FromSubject As String

    'Find Staff EUPN
    Dim cStaffEUPN As String
    Dim totalRow As Integer

    'Dim ConfigFile As String = AppPath + "\SharedClasses.cfg" ' Path to Data File
    Dim cDelimiter As String = ","                   ' Delimiter Character (TAB)
    Dim cQueryIS As String = String.Empty
    Dim cText As String
    'Define Student Structure
    Dim cStaffFrom As String
    Dim CStaffTo As String
    Dim cClass As String
    Dim MyFileNumber = FreeFile()
    'Start the Import
    FileOpen(MyFileNumber, cPath, OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read)
    cText = LineInput(MyFileNumber)
    Do While Not EOF(MyFileNumber)
        cText = ""
        cText = Trim(LineInput(MyFileNumber))
        If Left(cText, 1) <> ";" And cText <> "" Then

            'If Not Trim(vb.Left(cText, 1)) = cDelimiter Then
            'decode line
            cStaffFrom = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            cClass = VB.Left(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) - 1))
            cText = VB.Mid(cText, Val(InStr(cText, cDelimiter) + 1))
            CStaffTo = Trim(cText)
            '***********************************
            '*** Find Staff EUPN from System ***
            '***********************************
            'Staff has changed so load classes for that staff
            Dim stfSurname As String = VB.Left(cStaffFrom, Val(InStr(cStaffFrom, " ") - 1))
            Dim stfForename As String = VB.Mid(cStaffFrom, Val(InStr(cStaffFrom, " ") + 1))
            '
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            Dim query As String = String.Empty
            query = "SELECT EUPN FROM STAFF WHERE SURNAME = '" + stfSurname + "' AND FORENAME = '" & stfForename & "' AND ACCYEAR = '" & AccademicYear & "'"
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
                Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                    With comm
                        .Connection = conn
                        .CommandText = query
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    End With
                    Try
                        conn.Open()
                        reader = comm.ExecuteReader
                        Do While reader.Read
                            'this only retrieves the 1st column of the record.
                            If Not reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
                                cStaffEUPN = Trim(CStr(reader(0)))
                                FromStaffEUPN = cStaffEUPN
                            End If

                        Loop
                    Catch ex As SqlException
                        WriteToLogFile("SAVE FIND EUPN", ex.Message.ToString())
                        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR....")
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
            '**********************************
            '**** Get To Staff EUPN Number ****
            '**********************************
            stfSurname = VB.Left(CStaffTo, Val(InStr(CStaffTo, " ") - 1))
            stfForename = VB.Mid(CStaffTo, Val(InStr(CStaffTo, " ") + 1))
            '
            'Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            'Dim query As String = String.Empty
            query = "SELECT EUPN FROM STAFF WHERE SURNAME = '" + stfSurname + "' AND FORENAME = '" & stfForename & "' AND ACCYEAR = '" & AccademicYear & "'"
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
                Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                    With comm
                        .Connection = conn
                        .CommandText = query
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    End With
                    Try
                        conn.Open()
                        reader = comm.ExecuteReader
                        Do While reader.Read
                            'this only retrieves the 1st column of the record.
                            If Not reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
                                cStaffEUPN = Trim(CStr(reader(0)))
                                ToStaffEUPN = cStaffEUPN
                            End If

                        Loop
                    Catch ex As SqlException
                        WriteToLogFile("178: ", ex.Message.ToString())
                        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR....")
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using

            '********************************************************************************************
            'Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            'Dim query As String = String.Empty
            'cClass = VB.Left(cbClass.SelectedItem, Val(InStr(cbClass.SelectedItem, " ") - 1))
            query = "SELECT CLASS, SUBJECTCODE, SUBJECT FROM STAFFCLASSES WHERE EUPN = '" + FromStaffEUPN + "' AND CLASS = '" & cClass & "' AND ACCYEAR = '" & AccademicYear & "'"
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
                Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                    With comm
                        .Connection = conn
                        .CommandText = query
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    End With
                    Try
                        conn.Open()
                        reader = comm.ExecuteReader
                        Do While reader.Read
                            'this only retrieves the 1st column of the record.
                            If Not reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
                                FromClass = Trim(CStr(reader(0)))
                                FromSubjectCode = Trim(CStr(reader(1)))
                                FromSubject = Trim(CStr(reader(2)))
                            Else
                                FromClass = ""
                                FromSubjectCode = ""
                                FromSubject = ""
                            End If
                        Loop
                    Catch ex As SqlException
                        WriteToLogFile("207: ", ex.Message.ToString())
                        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR....")
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
            '**********************************************************************
            '**** Now we have the FROM Class, Write it Back with TO STAFF EUPN ****
            '**********************************************************************
            '**************************************
            '*** Is student already in database ***
            '**************************************
            'Dim query As String = String.Empty
            query = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM StaffClasses WHERE EUPN = '" & ToStaffEUPN & "' AND CLASS = '" & FromClass & "' AND ACCYEAR = '" & AccademicYear & "'"
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
                Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                    With comm
                        .Connection = conn
                        .CommandText = query
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    End With
                    Try
                        conn.Open()
                        Dim count As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(comm.ExecuteScalar())
                        totalRow = count
                    Catch ex As SqlException
                        WriteToLogFile("Find Student (SAVE Provision)", ex.Message.ToString())
                        MsgBox("Find Student - " & ex.Message.ToString())
                        'Write to log file
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
            '**** Is student there ****
            If totalRow = 0 Then
                '*****************************
                '**** No student Then Add ****
                '*****************************
                cQueryIS = "INSERT INTO StaffClasses (ACCYear, EUPN, Class, SubjectCode, Subject)  "
                cQueryIS &= "VALUES (@cAccYear, @cSTEupn, @cClass, @cSubjectCode, @cSubject)"
                Using dbConnectionSQL As New SqlConnection(dbConnectionString)
                    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                        With comm
                            .Connection = dbConnectionSQL
                            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            .CommandText = cQueryIS
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cAccYear", AccademicYear)
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cSTEupn", ToStaffEUPN)
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cClass", FromClass)
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cSubjectCode", FromSubjectCode)
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cSubject", FromSubject)
                        End With
                        Try
                            dbConnectionSQL.Open()
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            'Dim msgText As String
                            'msgText = "Class has been copied from" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                            'msgText &= "From staff member:" & vbCrLf
                            'msgText &= cbStaffMember.SelectedItem & vbCrLf
                            'msgText &= FromClass & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                            'msgText &= "To staff member:" & vbCrLf
                            'msgText &= cbStaffMemberTo.SelectedItem
                            'MsgBox(msgText, MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Copy Class...")
                        Catch ex As SqlException
                            WriteToLogFile("Add Provision", ex.Message.ToString())
                            MsgBox("262: - " & ex.Message.ToString() + vbCrLf + AccademicYear + vbCrLf + ToStaffEUPN + vbCrLf + FromClass + vbCrLf + FromSubjectCode + vbCrLf + FromSubject)
                        End Try
                    End Using
                End Using
            Else
                'Dim msgText As String
                'msgText = "Class has NOT been copied" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                'msgText &= "Class for staff member:" & vbCrLf
                'msgText &= cbStaffMember.SelectedItem & vbCrLf
                'msgText &= FromClass & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                'msgText &= "Alread Exists for staff member:" & vbCrLf
                'msgText &= cbStaffMemberTo.SelectedItem
                'MsgBox(msgText, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Copy Class...")
            End If
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Don't you think showing us some code might make it easier for us to debug your code ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code as it works, just not when you run it one after the other. I'm asking how to use Transactions.

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with the code, then this question is obviously not for SO. If you're searching info about transactions in VB.NET, try Google...

Comment: Code added, this is just the bit that read the text file and writes to Database. You can see how I do the selections and searches in SQL

Comment: Transactions are not meant for buffering data and they do not buffer it anyway. About your question, how many connections to single database you hold open? Have you some recordsets open? How  do you update your data exactly? Like said already, show us your 'correct code' - from what I have seen, every program behaves exactly like it is written. /edit - well, you updated question, thanks! Looking at sql with other tools, does data appear there after your inserts?/

Comment: Hi both, both SUBS added, they are called straight after each other the second one says data missing, I told the programme to skip the first sub as I had run it and only run the second sub and it works fine.

Comment: IN the 2nd code, you open connection 5 times. Where does it not get the right data? Everywhere? What data does not not load?

Comment: It fails on the last insert command: **.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cClass", FromClass)** says class not supplied, but if I run the routine again it works?